# Android Studio : Cannot resolve any method related to activity in all .java files

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, resolve

while coding in android studio suddenly all methods related to activities cannot resolve and shows error I don't know what happened :|for convenience i added the pic below

[image]

Comment: What are the error messages? Did you clean and rebuild your project? Does `MainActivity` extend `Activity` (either directly or indirectly)? If you depend on the compatibility libraries, is the project properly configured for them? Any import errors?

Comment: thankyou @TedHopp by cleaning the project it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :) by just cleaning the project thanks Ted Hopp